# How to query all data in firebase realtime?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to compare text with data from firebase. Below is my code and it reads name only from ing01. but actually i want it to read from all ingredient data, not only ing01. Please help me, thank you.

[image: database screenshot]

```
               final String dataCompare=sb.toString();//.replaceAll("\\s+","");



                databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ingredients");//.child("ing01").child("iName");

                databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                            String iName = ds.child("iName").getValue(String.class);

                            if(dataCompare.equals(iName)){

                                mResultEt.setText(dataCompare);
                                mStatusEt.setText("OK");
                                mStatusEt.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                            }
                            else{
                                mResultEt.setText(dataCompare);
                                mStatusEt.setText("Not OK");
                                mStatusEt.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: already add the screenshot. could you help me resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ingredients").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
        new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                   String iName = childSnapshot.child("iName").getValue(String.class);

                   //Implement your logic here
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        }
);
```

Here you will get all the `ingredients` and through iteration you get the `iName`.

But According your implementation logic. It's useless to get all the ingredients, rather you can get the specific ingredient matching your `compare` query. Try like below:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ingredients").orderByChild("iName").equalTo(dataCompare).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
        new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
                    mResultEt.setText(dataCompare);
                    mStatusEt.setText("OK");
                    mStatusEt.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                } else {
                    mResultEt.setText(dataCompare);
                    mStatusEt.setText("Not OK");
                    mStatusEt.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        }
);
```

Comment: I have tried your code but its still not working. There is no output. I also check the logcat but there is no error stated

Comment: Where you find no output? dataSnapshot.getChildren()?

Comment: When i run my app, there is nothing happen after i input value of data compare.

Comment: You have to implement your logic inside `onDataChange`. I mentioned with comment. Do you add your logic?

Comment: What is your logic? What do you want to do?

Comment: if data compare equal to iName, it will set Result textview with iName value, Status textview with iStatus value

Comment: Please update your code with current implementation. So that I can understand what are you doing

Comment: Your logic is wrong? You want to loop through multiple ingredients and want to update same TextView, which overwrite  each other. Then How can you see the output?

Comment: may i know which part it overwrite? the name is different. for name mResultEt and another 1 is mStatusEt

Comment: Suppose you search for **Test A**, then first iteration **if** execute and  second iteration **else** is executed. Am I clear to you?

Comment: I think actually you need: **FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ingredients").orderByChild("iName").equalTo(dataCompare)**. Please check with that

Comment: Your code works fine with me but i did amend some part to suit my project goal, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `firebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ingredients").child("ing01").child("iName");`, use `firebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ingredients");` for getting all ingredients

Comment: @juniorprogrammer you have to get all the childs and iterate through them using a loop, check here https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events

Comment: for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
if(dataSnapshot.child("iName").getValue().equals(dataCompare)){
mResultEt.setText(dataCompare);  mStatusEt.setText("OK");
                                }
                                else{
                                    mResultEt.setText(dataCompare);
                                    mStatusEt.setText("Not OK");
                                }
I followed your suggestion but still no output. Mayi know what is wrong with my code?

Comment: @juniorprogrammer there is no child `iName` directly under `ingredients`. you should get `ing01` first then `iName`

Answer (score 0):

you can used a third party library like: Angularfire here is there official link: https://github.com/angular/angularfire

Comment: Since OP is using Android, the AngularFire library isn't likely of much use to them.

Comment: what do they used by the way?

Answer (score 0):

```
final String dataCompare=sb.toString();
databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ingredients");

databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        String iName1 = dataSnapshot.child("ing01").child("iName");

        String iName2 = dataSnapshot.child("ing02").child("iName");

        //now here you can compare both the iName values with the dataCompare object.
    }
}
```

**** **EDIT** ****

```
final String dataCompare=sb.toString();
Log.d("DataCompare: ", dataCompare);

databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ingredients");

databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        if (dataSnapshot.getChildren() == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: snapshot has no children");

        } else {
            int i = 1;
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String iName = ds.child("ing0" + i++).child("iName").getValue();

                // if this doesn't work try this -- 
                // String iName = ds.child("iName").getValue();

                Log.d(TAG, "name value: " + iName);
                if (iName.equals(dataCompare)) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: string equals");

                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: strings are not equal");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Inside the `onDataChange()` method I wrote :-

```
String iName = ds.child("ing0" + i++).child("iName").getValue();
```

here we are reading the child "ing01" (in the first iteration of the loop) of the datasnapshot which is currently at "ingredients", and then we read "iName" and its value into `iName` string object.

for each loop will do this for all the children of the `dataSnapshot` which means for all the data you have in your firebase database.

Comment: what's the error? is your dataSnapshot object null?

Comment: how to know whether dataSnapshot is null or not? there is no error showed on logcat

Comment: @RohitRawat, dataSnapshot never null inside `onDataChange` as it annotated with NonNull.

Comment: yes but it's child can be null. so @juniorprogrammer check if(dataSnapshot.child("ing01") == null) then show log message

Comment: @RohitRawat That's a correct way for comparing the value of those properties but please provide some explanations, not only the code.